# I have a problem with javascript, Giulio Cesare's cipher

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a javascript code that implements the Cipher of Caesar, I tried but it doesn't work, I think that the problem is in the for loop in the functions that I used, I thank everyone who will help me.

```js
function Figure() {
  text = eval(send.t.value);
  key = eval(send.k.value);

  for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    tf.charCodeAt(i) = t.charCodeAt(i) + k;

    if (t.charAt(i) > 'Z') {
      tf.charCodeAt(i) = (('A' - 1) + (tf.charCodeAt(i) - 'Z'));
    }
  }

  send.value.mc = messaggiocifrato;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cryptography of Giulio Cesare</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Cryptography of Giulio Cesare</h1>

  <form name="send">
    Enter text to encrypt
    <input type="text" name="t"> <br/><br/> Enter key
    <input type="text" name="k"> <br/><br/> Encrypted text.
    <input type="text" name="tf"> <br/><br/>

    <input type="button" value="Figura" onclick="Figure()">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use of `eval` is generally frowned upon. Can you post a sample of your input and the expected output?

Comment: `I tried but it doesn't work` is very unspecific.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to ask a specific question. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code, I'll point out the first one and leave the rest for you to solve (lest I write all your code for you, and undermine the lessons you'll learn by debugging yourself!)

You're not using a library which enables you to refer to the values of your fields as `send.t.value` or `send.k.value`, which is why you're getting the error message `"ReferenceError: t is not defined"`. `send` is `undefined`, so trying to get the `t` property of `undefined` is causing this error.

You want to use something like `document.getElementsByName("t")[0].value` instead to get the value of `t`. You can read the MDN docs on this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)